# Click a text on the renderOption close the renderOption in AutoComplete | MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I like to change the order of the list based on the sort option.

I added the sort option in the `renderOption`. However, clicking the that sort option close the options.

What is happening right now is that click the `TextInput` to see all of the options > click the `Sort` FormControl to see all the sort options > you can see the renderOption is closed.

I like to leave the renderOption open even if I click the `Sort` text also after selecting one of the options in that sort selector.

Is there a way to keep the option open?

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  const renderOption = (props, option, state) => {
    return (
      <>
        {top100Films[0].label === option.label && (
          <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                id="demo-simple-select"
                value={age}
                label="Sort"
                onChange={handleChange}
              >
                <MenuItem value={10}>Date</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>A to Z</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={30}>???</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </Box>
        )}
        <li key={option.label} {...props}>
          {option.label}
        </li>
      </>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      renderOption={renderOption}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { label: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { label: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { label: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
    year: 2003
  },
  { label: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { label: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
    year: 2001
  },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
    year: 1980
  },
  { label: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
    year: 2002
  },
  { label: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { label: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { label: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { label: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
    year: 1977
  },
  { label: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { label: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { label: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { label: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { label: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { label: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { label: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { label: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { label: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { label: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { label: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { label: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { label: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { label: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { label: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { label: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { label: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { label: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { label: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { label: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { label: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { label: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { label: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { label: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { label: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { label: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { label: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { label: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { label: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { label: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    label:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { label: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { label: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { label: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { label: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { label: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { label: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { label: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { label: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { label: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { label: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { label: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { label: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { label: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { label: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { label: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { label: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
    year: 1983
  },
  { label: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { label: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { label: "M", year: 1931 },
  { label: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { label: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { label: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { label: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { label: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { label: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { label: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  {
    label: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind",
    year: 2004
  },
  { label: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { label: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { label: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { label: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { label: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { label: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { label: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { label: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { label: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { label: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { label: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { label: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { label: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { label: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { label: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { label: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```